# What does "Somebody cue the chorus of angels, would you?" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Some young girl in trouble and a gallant knight come to rescue her. Then she say "Somebody cue the chorus of angels, would you?" What does 'cue' mean in this case?
Does it mean "Tell the choir to start singing" or "Invite the choir" or something else?

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you? We are more than happy to help you out but we need to know what you're unclear about. There are only a couple of definitions of "cue"... which do you think is the most likely, which unlikely? Please [edit] your question to add this information!

Comment: To cue something in a recording studio means to put it in a list to be played or something like that. I don't know too much about recording studios, but one does hear that. Cue this or that.

Comment: Since the usage quoted is ironic or sarcastic, I don't think closing it was appropriate.  The usage questioned is certainly not literal. The dictionary definition can't tell you when a word or phrase is being used sarcastically or ironically. The original could be sarcastic to be making fun of the gallant knight, or it could be ironic, intended to evoke a romantic movie entrance of a cute guy the young girl might like to engage romantically. The OP might reword the question to make clear that their confusion results from the unlikely usage of the verb "cue" in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cue: a signal to a performer to begin a specific speech or action
>   *(Longman Family Dictionary*).

in this case, it is a signal to the chorus that it is time for them to start singing.

Comment: Not necessarily. If this is a recording studio, it could mean play that track. Put it in the play cue. Not sure but something like that.

Comment: @Lambie - If you're putting it in the ____, it's *queue*, not *cue*.

Comment: Not in American English. Take a look: http://www.nightflightmusic.com/services.html We had to rewind and forward the tapes just to cue the songs.

Comment: @Lambie - Yes, and he's using [cue](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cue) as a verb, like "[cue up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cue+up)".  If you want a noun, it's [queue](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/queue).

Comment: @Stangdon I repeat: not necessarily in American English. But here, it does seem to mean: tell the angels to start singing.